# Postfix Bounce Messages before refering to fallback relay

Tags: postfix

Atm the postfix server is sending a bounce message if the email is rejected. If its temporarily not delivered it refers the mail to the fallback relay and then after a while if it could not deliver it will send from the fallback server a bounce message that it could not deliver this message.

So my question is: Is it possible that the postfix server will send a bounce message **before** refering to the fallback relay?

So if the mail could not be temporarily delivered by both server it should generate **2 bounce messages**. Each for one server.

Comment: you shouldn't send bounce messages unless you  mean 400/500 smtp response, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email)

Comment: Perhaps you dont understand it, the bouncemessage is generated by postfix and sended to me ...